# Remote Desktop printing issue

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, printer

I have the following scenario:

- computer A (physical machine), Windows 7
- computer B (physical machine), Windows Server 2012
- computer C (virtual machine, located on computer B), Windows 7
- network printer

Computer A (admin account) connects to computer C through Remote Desktop RDP client (Microsoft default 6.1) leading to the following problem:

Once connected to computer B, I can freely install a network printer and everything works correctly.  When I log off and on to computer B, via RDP, the network printer no longer  works correctly.

In order to solve the problem I need to remove the network printer and then reinstall it.  Why does the network printer stop working after the user logs off?  Is there a way to work around the issue?

Comment: What printer, and how is it connected?  And what do you mean by `the network printer just doesn't work any more`?  Can you still ping it?  What happens to the print jobs?  Is there any information in the Event logs?

Comment: Please could you also let us know what type of network connection it is?  eg TCP/IP printer port, SMB, Jet-direct, something else?

Comment: It is a network printer and I can reach it through ping. What I mean when I say "ust doesn't work any more" is that the printer is available but it doesn't print so I remove it and then install it again (\\server name\network printer) Connection is through RDP port 3389

Comment: Okay, what type (manufacturer and model) of printer is it?  

So you are currently printing through the server?

Comment: I would recommend trying to set up a TCP/IP printer port: http://www.uta.edu/oit/cs/hardware/printing/addtcpipprtr2.php

Comment: Actually the network printer is set up with a tcp/ip port...Any user within the domain can use it. I'm just wondering if network printers through RDP protocol should be handled differently...in terms of set up or whatever

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer is inconsistent.  Are you installing the printer from the server, or manually installing the print drivers through the printer setup dialog boxes from the start menu, or control panel?

Answer (score 1):

You need to login to the server as administrator to the local session and install the same printerdrivers as you use on your normal machine. If done right, next time you connect, the printer will automatically be connected. (it must be the same driver, including 32 or 64 bits.

Alternatively, given that the printer is probably in the same network as the server, you can install the printer directly as a normal server printer and share it to all users. That way, the connected RDP user can access it directly. (which is probably the easiest method because its less prone to errors).

Comment: Thanks but I now realize I forgot to provide an important piece of information. computer C (virtual machine) is not part of the local domain. Given that, is your solution still applicable?

Comment: Yes, because it is a network printer, Computer C can still print using that method, regardless of how you setup the relation between A and B.